# Rgdal: writeOGR to SQLServer

Tags: r, rgdal

I am trying to write geodata to a Microsoft SQLServer 2017 using rgdal.

```
dsn = 'MSSQL:server=XXX;database=XXX;trusted_connection=yes'

data=data.frame(lat=c(52.52437), lon=c(13.41053), value=c("v"))
colnames(data) <- c("lat", "lon", "value")
data_coords = data
coordinates(data_coords) <- ~ lat + lon
data_sp = SpatialPointsDataFrame(data_coords, data)

writeOGR(data_sp, dsn=dsn, driver="MSSQLSpatial", layer="NewMSSQLSpatialTableName", layer_options=c("SRID=28355"), verbose=TRUE)
```

However, this code fails with:

```
> writeOGR(data_sp, dsn=dsn, driver="MSSQLSpatial", layer="NewMSSQLSpatialTableName", layer_options=c("SRID=28355"), verbose=TRUE)
Object initially classed as: wkbPoint
Error in writeOGR(data_sp, dsn = dsn, driver = "MSSQLSpatial", layer = "NewMSSQLSpatialTableName",  : 
  Layer creation failed
```

I have permissions to create tables in the database.
Am I missing additional permissions or did I do something else wrong?

Versions:

```
> library(rgdal)
rgdal: version: 1.2-16, (SVN revision 701)
 Geospatial Data Abstraction Library extensions to R successfully loaded
 Loaded GDAL runtime: GDAL 2.2.0, released 2017/04/28
 Path to GDAL shared files: C:/Users/User/Software/R/R-3.4.3/library/rgdal/gdal
 GDAL binary built with GEOS: TRUE 
 Loaded PROJ.4 runtime: Rel. 4.9.3, 15 August 2016, [PJ_VERSION: 493]
 Path to PROJ.4 shared files: C:/Users/User/Software/R/R-3.4.3/library/rgdal/proj
 Linking to sp version: 1.2-7
```

Comment: I'd  try a different data set, more than one point at least, or an established data set like wrld_simpl in maptools, with CRS set already.  It's a bit painful, but I recommend using GDAL from the command line to get this prototyped first, just in case it's an rgdal nuance.  Also, you might try sf::st_write with its format, it's more modern and has a shorter distance to GDAL itself.

Comment: @mdsummer Writing wrdl_simple using st_write sadly fails:   no applicable method for 'st_write' applied to an object of class "c('SpatialPolygonsDataFrame', 'SpatialPolygons', 'Spatial')"

Comment: `st_write` uses the new spatial classes from the `sf` package, so some conversion is necessary from SpatialPolygons* objects.

Comment: I was assuming you would continue to use writeOGR as per your q, the st_write was after "Also". It is painfully fragmented, but worth trying those three alternatives (at least).